# What is the equivalent of @Context UriInfo in Spring Rest

Tags: spring-mvc, jersey, jax-rs, resteasy, spring-rest

I have worked in Jersey and RESTEasy framework earlier and now we will be using Spring Rest for a new project , I don't want to pass all the query params and matrix params as parameters in the method , and usually I would annotate the method with `@Context UriInfo` and would get all the parameters inside my method in Jersey or RESTEasy Framework for complex parameters.

I would like to know  if there is any  `@Context UriInfo` in Spring REST, which is similar to RESTEasy or Jersey Framework. I would like to get all the query params or matrix params and other params if any  inside the method instead of passing them as a parameter in the method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I did not find any spring class equivalent to UriInfo. 
But we can take same info from httpservlet request. Suppose, a url is http:localhost:8080/services/test?one=1&two=2,  then,

```
    hsr.getServletContext.getContextPath() gives "/services"
    hsr.getRequestURI() gives "/services/test"
    hsr.getRequestURL() gives complete url "http:localhost:8080/services/test"
    hsr.getQueryString() gives "one=1&two=2"
    hsr.getServletPath() gives "/test"
    hsr.getParameterMap() gives all query strings in a Map as key value pair
```

You can set and use these values in URIinfo object

Comment: If the request mapping use the path like this '/api/user/{id}', how can i get the '/api/user/' only, ignore the '{id}' PathVariable

Answer (score 2):

I think there isn't really a similar Api.
The options are either using `ServletContext` like already mentioned, or the following:

```
RequestAttributes reqAttributes =  RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes();
reqAttributes.getAttribute(BEST_MATCHING_PATTERN_ATTRIBUTE, 0);
```

This way is useful if you want to get the declared path, that is, with the PathVariables declaration. It won't show the actual values for the @PathVars.

This was already answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60167173/976948

Answer (score 1):

I also did not find any spring class equivalent to UriInfo. I am using as code below:

```
private getRequstUrl(HttpServletRequest request) {
    String requestUrl = request.getScheme() + "://" + request.getServerName()
    + ("http".equals(request.getScheme()) && request.getServerPort() == 80 || "https".equals(request.getScheme()) && 
    request.getServerPort() == 443 ? "" : ":" + request.getServerPort())
    + request.getRequestURI();
    return requestUrl;
}

public String constructLink(ParamModel paramModel, String requestUrl) {
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder("<");
    stringBuilder.append(requestUrl);
    if (paramModel.getSize() > 0 && paramModel.getStart() > -1) {
        stringBuilder.append("?");
        stringBuilder.append("start=");
        stringBuilder.append(paramModel.getStart() + paramModel.getSize());

        stringBuilder.append("&");

        stringBuilder.append("size=");
        stringBuilder.append(paramModel.getSize());
    }
    stringBuilder.append(">; rel=\"next\"");
    return stringBuilder.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Spring MVC you can also access it with:

```java
@Autowired
ServletContext servletContext;
```

However, it will give you a more limited set of available methods than  Kaliappan's approach.