# Spring REST get url path for multiple mapped endpoint

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have REST endpoint with multiple paths as following:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, path = {"/xxx/yyy", "/zzz"})
@ResponseBody
public Mono<EpcPain> paymentOrder(@RequestHeader(name = "Timeout", defaultValue = "10000") int timeout,
                                  @RequestHeader(name = "X-Request-Id", required = false) String xRequestId) {
...
}
```

How can I resolve if request path was xxx/yyy or zzz? I do not want to duplicate this endpoint nor pass some params. I am looking for some spring code magic.

Comment: Maybe you could try something like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/37718400

Comment: Will this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42650241/4214241) help ?

Comment: `ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentRequestUri().toUriString()` will get you the uri

Comment: Thnx R.G, but I do not want to add new dependency because of that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextHolder` may be used to get the path

```
import static org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerMapping.BEST_MATCHING_PATTERN_ATTRIBUTE;
import static org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerMapping.LOOKUP_PATH;
import static org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerMapping.PATH_WITHIN_HANDLER_MAPPING_ATTRIBUTE;
```

and

```
   @RequestMapping(value = {"/getDetails","/getDetailsMore"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getCustomerDetails(TestFormBean bean) {
        RequestAttributes reqAttributes = RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes();
    System.out.println(reqAttributes.getAttribute(BEST_MATCHING_PATTERN_ATTRIBUTE, 0));
    System.out.println(reqAttributes.getAttribute(LOOKUP_PATH, 0));
    System.out.println(reqAttributes.getAttribute(PATH_WITHIN_HANDLER_MAPPING_ATTRIBUTE, 0));

        return "test";
    }}
```

All three prints the path.

Here [0 - is request scope](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/d521d37f14f03688a17b6657df30ff533f2d5f9f/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/context/request/RequestAttributes.java#L38) and [1 - is session scope](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/d521d37f14f03688a17b6657df30ff533f2d5f9f/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/context/request/RequestAttributes.java#L46).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You could add [`ServerHttpRequest`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/server/ServerHttpRequest.html) as a method argument and then get the URI for the current request using [`getURI()`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/HttpRequest.html#getURI--). It should work for both Spring MVC and Spring WebFlux.

Have a look at the handler methods [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web-reactive.html#webflux-ann-methods) for details.