# @Context UriInfo replacement in Spring Boot app

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, servlets

I'm in the process of modernizing and transforming a legacy monolith application that runs in `Spring` on `Jetty` into a `Spring Boot` application.

In the legacy code, I have an endpoint that looks like that:

```
@POST
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
@Path("/zoo/feedCats")
@WebMethod
public Response giveFood( @Context UriInfo uri, HungryCats hungryCats){...}
```

And the first draft of the new endpoint in `Spring Boot` looks like that:

```
@PostMapping("/zoo/feedCats")
public Response giveFood( UriInfo uri , @RequestBody HungryCats hungryCats) {...}
```

I'm not sure what should be the right replacement for the `@Context UriInfo uri` that is in the legacy code.

I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34690109/what-is-the-equivalent-of-context-uriinfo-in-spring-rest) from 2016 and was wondering if there is something else to use?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Jersey, but [this may be what you are looking for](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55148387/1189885).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I solved it like that:

Created

```
class MyUriInfo implements UriInfo{..}
```

In the controller I changed the signature to be:

```
@PostMapping("/zoo/feedCats")
public Response giveFood(@RequestBody HungryCats hungryCats, 
                                      HttpServletRequest request,
                                      @RequestParam Map<String, String> allParams)
```

And created a translator method that takes what I need from the `request` and `allParams` and inject them to `MyUriInfo`:

```
 public UriInfo requestToUriInfo(HttpServletRequest request, Map<String, String> 
                                                               allParams) {
     ...
     retrun new MyUriInfo(...)
 }
```